# Better replacement rules to perform this change of variables?

Tags: differential-equations, replacement, symbolic, rule, coordinate-transformation

In cosmology, it is common to work with both a normal (a.k.a. “cosmic”) time variable `t` and a “conformal” time variable `τ`, which is defined such that `dt = a(t) dτ`. In other words, `d/dτ = a(t) d/dt`.

I have a bunch of expressions in conformal time that I want to convert to cosmic time. Right now, I am applying a bunch of explicit rules like this:

```
expressions /. {
    f[τ] -> f[t],
    f'[τ] -> a[t] f'[t],
    f''[τ] -> a[t] a'[t] f'[t] + a[t]^2 f''[t],
        ...
    g[τ] -> g[t],
    g'[τ] -> a[t] g'[t],
    g''[τ] -> a[t] a'[t] g'[t] + a[t]^2 g''[t],
        ...
}
```

Is there a simpler approach that (*a*) doesn't require me to perform the chain rule myself to work out the higher derivatives, and (*b*) doesn't require me to list separate rules for `f`, `g`, and all the other relevant symbols?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use `Derivative`:

```
rules = {func_[τ] /; MemberQ[{f, g, h}, func] :> func[t],
         Derivative[n_][func_][τ] /; MemberQ[{f, g, h}, func] :> D[func[t[τ]], {τ, n}], 
         Derivative[n_][t][τ] :> D[a[t[τ]], {τ, n - 1}]}
```

The first rule is needed to replace functions of `τ` with functions of `t`.  The next two rules tells *Mathematica* to take derivatives of the specific functions `f[τ]`, `g[τ]` and `h[τ]`.

The result will contain a bunch of `f[t[τ]]` and `g[t[τ]` *etc.*  So apply a finishing rule to remove the explicit dependence of `t` on `τ`:

```
finishingRule = {Derivative[n_][f_][t[τ]] :> Derivative[n][f][t], 
                 f_[t[τ]] :> f[t]}
```

Let's try it out:

```
 f[τ] + r[τ] - f'[τ] + g''[τ] //. rules /. finishingRule
```

> f[t] + r[τ] − a[t] f'[t] + a[t] a'[t] g'[t] + a[t]^2 g''[t]

Comment: Thank you. I see you have set up the rule to match *any* function of `τ` except `t`, which is probably what I want. But is there any way to explicitly match a specific list of functions `{f, g, h}` instead?

Comment: And more importantly, this solution nicely replaces `f'[τ]` or `f''[τ]` but does not make the necessary replacement to `f[τ]`.

Comment: @thecommexokid I have modified the rules so that `f[τ]` correctly gets replaced to `f[t]`, and changed the condition so that it looks only for `{f, g, h}`.